# PHP array help getting a value from the key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable that looks likes this,

```
$rslt['expected_salary_level']
```

This returns a string similar to LEVEL_3, in another array that looks like this I have a set of salaries,

```
    Array
(
    [LEVEL_1] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => under &pound;10,000
            [low] => 1
            [high] => 10000
        )

    [LEVEL_2] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;10,000 - &pound;15,000
            [low] => 10000
            [high] => 15000
        )

    [LEVEL_3] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;15,000 - &pound;20,000
            [low] => 15000
            [high] => 20000
        )

    [LEVEL_4] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;20,000 - &pound;25,000
            [low] => 20000
            [high] => 25000
        )

    [LEVEL_5] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;25,000 - &pound;30,000
            [low] => 25000
            [high] => 30000
        )

    [LEVEL_6] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;30,000 - &pound;40,000
            [low] => 30000
            [high] => 40000
        )

    [LEVEL_7] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;40,000 - &pound;50,000
            [low] => 40000
            [high] => 50000
        )

    [LEVEL_8] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;50,000 - &pound;100,000
            [low] => 50000
            [high] => 100000
        )

    [LEVEL_9] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => &pound;100,000 or more
            [low] => 100000
            [high] => 9999999
        )

    [LEVEL_VOLUNTARY] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => Voluntary
            [low] => 
            [high] => 
        )

    [LEVEL_UNSPECIFIED] => Array
        (
            [nice_name] => Not specified
            [low] => 
            [high] => 
        )

)
```

How do I get at the associated nice name?

Comment: What's wrong with `$thatArray['LEVEL_3']['nice_name']`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `$rslt['expected_salary_level']` returns the key for this array in your example. Assuming that this array is called `$array`, I think this is what you want:

```
$array[$rslt['expected_salary_level']]['nice_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple way to get array to array key values :

```
$own_array_result = $rslt['expected_salary_level']['LEVEL_3']['nice_name'];

echo $own_array_result;
```

OUTPUT => **£15,000 - £20,000**

Comment: plz format you ans [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)